# Malformed version number string undefined (ArgumentError) in fastlane in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, continuous-integration, fastlane, cicd

I am trying to upload build to appstore using fastlane in flutter. After Logging and selected team from appstore id. I am getting this error.

```
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/version.rb:214:in `initialize': Malformed version number string undefined (ArgumentError)
```